# Discord.js use fs.readFile for specific parts

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am trying to read my .json file to compare a channel ID to another channel ID. Problem I don't know how to read specific part of a .json file.

Current version:

```
fs.readFile("./test.json", function readFile(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return message.reply("Something went wrong.");
            }
            const id = data;

            if (message.channel.id === id) return message.reply("It works.");
            else return message.reply(`it does not work, data is ${data} and etc. is${message.channel.id}`);
        }) ;
```

My .json file:

```
{"logChannel":"717666711326687232"}
```

I only want to channel ID part so no logChannel, how would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The `require` function is the easiest way to include modules that exist in separate files.

```
const channels = require('./test.json');
let id = channels.logChannel;

// Outputs 717666711326687232
console.log(id);
```